# Jquery - Change several IDs inside a html file which is stored in a varaible

Tags: jquery

I have stored HTML code in a variable. In this HTML code are several elements with their own id. For each use, I have to change the elements Ids inside the stored HTML code.

After changing the Ids, I would like to manipulate the respective attributes of the elements. So far I tried following:

Changing the Ids:

```
$(myHtmlVariable).prev(elmId).attr('id',newId);
```

Manipulate the elements required attributes:

```
$(myHtmlVariable).prev(newId).attr('value',newValue);
...
```

But I am not sure this is right. Would be happy for some help.

Comment: How you achieve this entirely depends on what the HTML contains and what the value of `id` is. Please add it to the question.

Comment: *For each use, I have to change the element Ids* - do you?  Do you *really* have to?  It's highly likely that you don't need an `id` at all, especially if it's an auto-generated id like an incrementing number.

Comment: Assuming `myHtmlVariable` is a *string* then `$(myHtmlVariable)` will be in memory (not in the DOM) and so won't have any siblings to get when calling `.prev()`, maybe you meant `.find()` - but you still need to store the result of `$(myHtmlVariable)` (or the chain,  likely the same) otherwise it will be lost - debug your code on *every* step to see what you're getting, not just the last part of the chain.

Comment: You edit implies there are multiple elements in the html string that need changing - are you trying to change them *all* to the same value?

Comment: I have to use this html code (stored in the variable) more than once on the same page. So I need to have ids and different ids to be interactive. The html code is a string and I use nodejs  to work with jquery. So far it works fine on the serverside. As I am not deep in jquery, I am looking for a way to get the element by the default id, changing its id to the newId and after that using the newId to manipulate all the attributes of the element. Changing the id and the rest of the attributes should be the same approach.

Comment: Your comment above indicates that you do not need to give it an `id`.  If you have a reference to the element `var ref = $(myHtmlVariable)` then you can manipulate anything inside it *easier* than with an id.

Comment: What I try to explain is, that in this variable myHtmlVariable are several elements included. For example buttons, etc. I need to change the ids of these  elements inside the myHtmlVariable. There are 6 ids to change. I can retrieve them with: `$(myHtmlVariable).find("[id][id!='']").each(function(){ IDS.push(this.id); });` Now I want to change the default ids and I tried this with: `$(myHtmlVariable).find(IDS[x]).attr("id",setNewId);` But it doesn´t work

Comment: And what I'm trying to explain is that those IDs have no effect / no use / are redundant / are not needed.  Remove them from the original myHtmlVariable string.

Comment: You'll need to loop through your array:  `var h = $(myHtmlVariable); var ids = h.find("[id][id!='']").map(() { this.id }).toArray(); for (var i in ids) { h.find("#" + ids[i]).attr("id", ids[i]+new_suffix); }; $("#container").append(h);`

Comment: Given that myHtmlVariable is a *string*, `$(myHtmlVariable)` will create a *new* jquery object each time - my example above keeps this in memory instead of creating a new one each time.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the variable is wrong.

You should use it as context.

$(here comes your selectors, $(myHtmlVar)).doTheTrick();

Comment: I assume that the problem is what you wrote above, no siblings. so the OP(original post?) is failing there. my solution allows a search similar to your `find()` ...  i think that he(?) simply missed that part of the scope.